# Creating coloured background using mask - get error that 3 input values cannot be assigned where mask is true

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am trying to create an RGB background colour around a head which I have masked.

```
mask = np.ones(image.shape)
mask = cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, 0, cv2.FILLED)

output = image.copy()
output[mask != 0] = (255,0,0)
```

But I get the following error:

```
ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 3 input values to the 143184 output values where the mask is true
```

It works when using a single input:

```
mask = np.ones(image.shape)
mask = cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, 0, cv2.FILLED)

output = image.copy()
output[mask != 0] = 0
```

And gives the correct masking:

[image: masking]

However, I would ideally like to have the background red so when I later make the background transparent it doesn't affect anything in the face.

Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: make `mask` single channeled.

```
mask = np.ones(image.shape[:2])
```

Explanation:

This is because your `mask` is the same shape as `image` and you're trying to replace every single value with three. If you want to replace every three values, you should build query that would give access to three per operation.

In your code `output[mask != 0] = anything` puts `anything` instead of each value of each channel but only if it will fit the shape.

Let's say your image is 400x300 px RGB (or BGR, whatever with 3 channels), so its shape is 400x300x3. Since mask is the same shape, condition `mask != 0` points to each value of each channel. When mask is single channel, the condition points to each pixel wholly and then you can replace 3 existing values with 3 desired (still keeping the shape).

Comment: Thank you very much this works and your explanation clearly explains where I'd gone wrong.